# Embed Python interpreter in C

Tags: python, c, embed

I'm trying to run a very simple example of a main.c file to include and run some Python code. I have tried to compile and run this program but I get a library not loaded error

```
./main
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/$USER/GitRepos/python-embed/./main
  Reason: image not found
[1]    9323 abort      ./main
```

Any thoughts on what I might be missing? I've posted the code I'm using [here](https://github.com/kdheepak/python-embed/blob/master/main.c).

Comment: Check library dependency with `otool -L`. As a side note, use a debugger and step through it.

Comment: Your code worked for me with one small change to the Makefile (see https://pastebin.com/DWgmkC3Q)

Comment: I made the same change but it still throws the same error.

Comment: @YiFei thanks for the suggestion. It appears that `@rpath` is not able to find the libpython3.6 library. I'm no longer getting this error if I set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line worked for me.

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/$USER/miniconda3/lib
```

If anyone has a better way to do this let me know.